# Is there a "SELECT 1" in JPQL?

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpql

Is there some equivalent of "SELECT 1" or "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" for JPQL? Like a simple test query.

Comment: to achieve what? JPQL selects entities

Comment: Select e From Employee e

Comment: Are you asking whether you can select just the first row?

Comment: I'm looking to use it to test a connection to the database.

Comment: The JPA implementation is there to "test the connection to the database" so you don't have to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is getResultList, which returns query results as an untyped List. And you can use setMaxResults, limiting it to 1:

```
query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

Or else you can say the following which returns a single untyped result:

```
query.getSingleResult()
```

The EntityManager API also allows creation of native queries, which may be your simplest approach:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select 1 from sometable").getSingleResult();
```

For details, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html.

Comment: Thanks J Woodchuck! I'm surprised that JPQL doesn't have a "SELECT 1" out of the box. I've tried getSingleResult(), but it only works with a non-empty table. I'm using two different types of databases for production and preproduction, so I can't run the native query without finding out what driver (oracle, h2, etc.) is being used. That I attempted to do, but ran into a lot of issues with the entity manager and JPA